# Adding JSON array to a JSONObject without the quotes for the value of JSON Array in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am trying to add a JSONArray toa JSONObject using the code below:

```
   defObj.put("locArr",(Object)locArr);
```

But this is resulting in the following format of JSON:

```
   ["locArr":"[{"longitude":35,"latitude":39,"ip":"81.212.204.150"},
               {"longitude":-122.1781,"latitude":37.459,"ip":"173.252.110.27"}]"]
```

I am initializing and populating locArr as shown below:

```
   JSONObject locObj = new JSONObject();
   JSONArray locArr = new JSONArray();
   locObj.put("ip", ip);
   locObj.put("latitude", latitude);
   locObj.put("longitude", longitude);
       locArr.put(locObj)
```

As you can see the value of the JSONArray is being enclosed in double quotes. Because of this, when I am trying to parse this JSON, I am facing an Unexpected character error because of the quote.

I want the output like below:

```
   ["locArr":[{"longitude":35,"latitude":39,"ip":"81.212.204.150"},
               {"longitude":-122.1781,"latitude":37.459,"ip":"173.252.110.27"}]]
```

Could anyone please let me know how to add the value of JSONArray without enclosing with double quotes?

Comment: Can you show us how you initialize and populate locArr?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I have updated the question. Please check

Comment: Where are you trying to parse JSON ? in javascript?

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev I am trying to parse it in JAVA

Comment: Share how you want the output to look like. Do you mean you want to remove the quotes from "locArr"?

Comment: @Ayman Please find the output format. I have updated the question.

Comment: Did you get solution to this @SrikanthKandalam

Answer (score 4):

I think you need an enclosing JSON array :

```
JSONObject locObj = new JSONObject();
locObj.put("ip", ip);
locObj.put("latitude", latitude);
locObj.put("longitude", longitude);

// Inner array
JSONArray locArr = new JSONArray(); 
locArr.put("locArr", locObj);

// Parent array
JSONArray parentArr = new JSONArray();
parentArray.put(locArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the object casting:

```
defObj.put("locArr", locArr);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this and it resulted in this format:

       "locArr":["[{"longitude":35,"latitude":39,"ip":"81.212.204.150"},{"longitude":35,"latitude":39,"ip":"212.156.101.117"}]"]

Comment: Please share the whole method body so I can run it locally and revert back.